# Responsive text fixed positioning with Button

Tags: html, css, wordpress

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEWog.png

I am currently trying to work out how to make the 'From £' text to keep in the same position as the buttons above. The page is responsive so I have been unable to keep the text in one position.

The CSS I have used so far -

```
element.style {position: absolute; width: 97%;}
```

I put each of the 'From £' parts in their own class. Not sure if there is an easier way?

```
<div class="price2">From £300</div>
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Can you include some more context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a container for the element for the price and button so that they remain in context with each other.
http://jsfiddle.net/05orkj1a/

```
.prices{
    width: 100%;
 }
.price-column{
   display: table-cell;
   width: 33%;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0 5px;
}
```

---

```
<div class="prices">
    <div class="price-column">
        <button>Bass</button>
        <div class="price2">From £65</div>
    </div>
    <div class="price-column">
        <button>Mid</button>
        <div class="price2">From £300</div>
    </div>
    <div class="price-column">
        <button>Treble</button>
        <div class="price2">From £715</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could also Float the columns left to cause them to collapse vertically as the screen shrinks with the same html. Just change the margin or padding depending on how far apart you want them spaced

http://jsfiddle.net/z6agt11e/

```
.prices{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
.price-column{
   display: block;
   float: left;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 5px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS3 ::after pseudo-selector.

Give at button class:

```
position: relative;
```

Then you have to write something lime this:

```
.button-class::after {
   content: 'From £300';
   background: transparent;
   height: 1%;
   width: 3%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 20px;
   left: 0px;
}
```

Obviously, you have to change `height: 1%; width: 3%;` and `top: 20px; left: 0px;`with whatever you want!

Comment: What if the prices were obtained from a database or plugin like WooCommerce?

Comment: Well you can put this CSS code inside the page .php:

<style>
.button-class::after {
   content: '<?php echo $string; ?>';
   background: transparent;
   height: 1%;
   width: 3%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 20px;
   left: 0px;
}
</style>

Comment: When developing an HTML5/CSS3 site I try to avoid inline-styles and recommend using `content: attr(data-content)` from within the .css file. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/sku9ce7m/ That way you can do `<button data-content="<?php echo $string; ?>">Text</button>`  I then use JavaScript to support older browsers that do not have CSS3 enabled. I hope you find this method useful in the future.

Comment: Here is an example with JavaScript `::after` detection like I mentioned using Modernizr and emulated lack of CSS3 support. http://jsfiddle.net/tghat5yq/ It simply appends a span into the element similarly to how ::after works.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add an outer container and then create a inner container for each button-price set.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="outter">
<div class="block">
   <div class="button">button1</div>
      <div class="price2">From £65</div>
      </div>
   <div class="block">
      <div class="button">button2</div>
      <div class="price2">From £300</div>
   </div>
   <div class="block">
      <div class="button">button3</div>
      <div class="price2">From £715</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here the CSS:

```
.outter{
width:100%;    
} 

.block{
width:33%;
background-color: yellow;
float:left;
text-align: center;
}
```

And here a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/SoniaGM/ej4mdwx9/1/

Hope it helps.